# Ajax validation in pjax form in yii2

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pjax

I am using ajax validation in pjax form like this

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?> 
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'address-details-form',                                
 'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal','data-pjax' => true,],
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
  ]); ?>
 //My form
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end();
```

After submit the form it will post some model data like this

> "personaldetails-manual_address_line1":["You must enter Address Line1"],"personaldetails-manual_address_line2":["You must enter Address Line2"],"personaldetails-manual_address_line3":["You must enter Address Line3"],"personaldetails-manual_address_line4":["You must enter Address Line4"],

Actually it is my model rules why it happens.But i am remove ajax validation means it is working fine,but i want ajax validation

Answer (score 0):

You have to have this in your controller

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

This should be just after you do your

```
$model = new [ModelClass]();
```

See more details here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation

Comment: Yes i did this in my controller action

Comment: can you try without 'data-pjax' => true ?

Comment: I do not think you can get both pjax and ajax working, as they will step on each other toes. make ajax work first and then you can do the pjax part.

Comment: Anyway figure out what the problem is first, step by step, make ajax validation work without pjax, afterwards enable pjax and make it work again (if that is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got pjax form with ajax validation.I combine ajax in my controller like this

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
```

I don't no it is write or wrong my friend ganasa suggest to me.It is working fine for me.